# Proper wording for lottery skewed by contribution size

Tags: terminology

I have an idea for a lottery that is skewed in a fairly simple way:

The chance of winning is proportional to the square of each player's contribution, divided by the sum of the square of all players' contributions.

It might be expressed this way:

```
Chance of winning = contribution^2 / 
                    (contribution1^2 + contribution2^2 + ... + contributionN^2)
```

I'm looking for a concise and accurate way of describing this, and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a layperson, the most salient feature is that as you buy more tickets, your chances increase in a better-than-linear fashion. You could say, "we square the number of tickets you buy. That means if you buy 2 tickets instead of 1, your chances of winning are quadrupled. If you buy 4 tickets, your chances are 16 times higher!" You could illustrate this with some pictures of squares with sides of 1, 2, and 4 units, broken down into unit squares. It's a geometric progression, though I think laypeople tend to (incorrectly) call it "exponential".